# How to delete row after update in IF/ELSE statement?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, if-statement

My scenario -> I need to update record if exists and delete old one(I'm sure "old one exist") after update, else insert "old one". I cannot run `DELETE` query after `IF EXISTS` since it may happen than old one will be needed (will be inserted from ELSE statement).

Here is my attempt :

```
IF EXISTS (SELECT * FROM dbo.JDOMINO_CON WHERE GBC = '72227')  
   UPDATE dbo.JDOMINO_CON 
   SET GBC = '72227', 
       Description = 'RES_TF,10k,0402,1%,0,1W,100PPM/C', 
       Buildneed = Buildneed + 200, 
       Replaced = '72223' 
   WHERE GBC = '72227'

DELETE FROM dbo.JDOMINO_CON 
WHERE GBC = '72223' /* If updated I need to delete replaced row */

ELSE /*Here is error : Incorrect syntax near 'ELSE'*/
    INSERT INTO dbo.JDOMINO_CON (GBC,Description, Buildneed, Replaced) 
    VALUES ('72227', 'RES_TF,10k,0402,1%,0,1W,100PPM/C', 200, NULL)
```

Sample data :

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[JDOMINO_CON] 
(
    [GBC]         INT          NULL,
    [Description] VARCHAR (80) NULL,
    [Buildneed]   INT          NULL,
    [Replaced]    VARCHAR (80) NULL
);

INSERT INTO @JDOMINO_CON (GBC, [Description], Buildneed, Replaced)
SELECT 72227, 'RES_TF,10k,0402,1%,0,1W,100PPM/C', 200, NULL
UNION ALL
SELECT 72223, 'RES_TF,10k,0402,5%,0,1W,100PPM/C', 200, NULL
UNION ALL
```

Expected output --> only 1 row --> 72227 /'RES_TF,10k,0402,1%,0,1W,100PPM/C'/ Buildneed = 400 / Replaced = 72223

So my question is: how can I add delete statement if record exists?

Comment: If you want to run both the `UPDATE` and the `DELETE` only when the `IF EXISTS()` is true, then you need to put these two statements into a `BEGIN ..... END` block. Otherwise, the `IF EXISTS()` **only** applies to the **one, next statement** .... (only to the `UPDATE` statement)

Comment: Thank You very much @marc_s thats exactly what i have missed. Meanwhile i've tryed to put DELETE statement in BEGIN...END now i understood why it failed

Comment: Aside: You could remove the `exists` query and go straight to the `update`. After that check the value of [`@@RowCount`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/rowcount-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15). If it is zero then `insert`, otherwise `delete`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to execute more than one sql statement in the `IF` or `ELSE` branch, then you need to declare a *statement block*: this means wrapping them two queries in a `BEGIN/END` block, as explained [in the documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/language-elements/if-else-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15):

> Unless a statement block is used, the `IF` or `ELSE` condition can affect the performance of only one Transact-SQL statement.
>
> To define a statement block, use the control-of-flow keywords `BEGIN` and `END`.

In your code:

```
IF EXISTS(SELECT * FROM dbo.JDOMINO_CON WHERE GBC = '72227') 
BEGIN
    UPDATE dbo.JDOMINO_CON SET GBC = '72227', Description = 'RES_TF,10k,0402,1%,0,1W,100PPM/C', Buildneed = Buildneed + 200, Replaced = '72223' WHERE GBC = '72227'
    DELETE FROM dbo.JDOMINO_CON WHERE GBC = '72223'
END
ELSE 
INSERT INTO dbo.JDOMINO_CON (GBC,Description, Buildneed, Replaced) VALUES('72227', 'RES_TF,10k,0402,1%,0,1W,100PPM/C', 200, NULL);
```

**[Demo on DB Fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=2731a7de8acf2dec8c6052cadc9469c7)**

Comment: Thank You very much for briefly explanation, i've tryed with UPDATE ... BEGIN DELETE END ELSE.. Now i understand why it failed.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the corrected format of the SQL Server query.

```
IF EXISTS (
        SELECT *
        FROM dbo.JDOMINO_CON
        WHERE GBC = '72227'
        )
BEGIN
    UPDATE dbo.JDOMINO_CON
    SET GBC = '72227'
        ,[Description] = 'RES_TF,10k,0402,1%,0,1W,100PPM/C'
        ,Buildneed = Buildneed + 200
        ,Replaced = '72223'
    WHERE GBC = '72227'

   --Your delete statement will be here.
   DELETE FROM dbo.JDOMINO_CON 
   WHERE GBC = '72223' /* If updated I need to delete replaced row */
END
ELSE
BEGIN
    INSERT INTO dbo.JDOMINO_CON (
        GBC
        ,Description
        ,Buildneed
        ,Replaced
        )
    VALUES (
        '72227'
        ,'RES_TF,10k,0402,1%,0,1W,100PPM/C'
        ,200
        ,NULL
        )
END
```

Here is the live [demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=76e2466627b681fa87e872ebb8ba7dd4) for the query. You need to debug and change the exists query for your desired result.

Comment: Any reason for the downvoting?

Comment: I haven't down vote, but this will not do what i need

Comment: @KubaDo no issue I had corrected the syntax and already added a comment for the debug. I think you had to include the Delete statement while checking if exists or something else?

Comment: Only that, but You have included delete in else statement. Please check accepted answer

Comment: @KubaDo OK got it. Thanks.